# Custom parameter with Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect and AzureAD v 2.0 endpoint

Tags: azure, owin, openid-connect, azure-active-directory

I am migrating my Azure AD secured application to the v2.0 endpoint.

I need to pass a custom parameter to the reply uri. With former Azure AD endpoint I did it by adding a usual query parameter to the reply url. `e.g. https://myserver.com/myredirect_uri?mycustomparamerter=myvalue`

Unfortunately, with endpoint 2.0 I received an error saying that the reply uri does not match the one registered. Of course my custom parameter value is dynamic and I cannot hardcode it.

I was looking to exploit the 'state' parameter [described in OAUTH flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). However, `I am using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect` and it looks the parameter is already set so I cannot exploit it. I am using an implementation of the flow that is based on MVC that looks like [this sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-dotnet-web/).

Can you suggest a workaround so my server receive a custom parameter in the reply url that have been set on the flow start?

Comment: It has been asked here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/14758953-support-query-parameters-in-reply-urls-with-azure

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure if there's an official way to do what you're asking but one way you could technically inject and extract extra values through the auth flow is via OWIN's notifications.

In Startup.Auth.cs, when you setup the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions you'd add the following:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
  new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
  {
    //...
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
      RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
      MessageReceived = OnMessageReceived
    },
  });
```

And use RedirectToIdentityProvider to inject your parameter, something along the lines of:

```
private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
  var stateQueryString = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=');
  var protectedState = stateQueryString[1];
  var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
  state.Dictionary.Add("mycustomparameter", "myvalue");
  notification.ProtocolMessage.State = stateQueryString[0] + "=" + notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(state);
  return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

And then use MessageReceived to extract it, like so:

```
private Task OnMessageReceived(MessageReceivedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
  string mycustomparameter;
  var protectedState = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=')[1];
  var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
  state.Dictionary.TryGetValue("mycustomparameter", out mycustomparameter);
  return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

You'd obviously need to improve/harden this but this should get you going barring a better overall approach.

Comment: Thank you. I will investigate this.

Comment: It works but this will complicate our flow. It is unclear from OpenIdConnect and OAUTH spec whether reply url with query parameters should be allowed. I would like to ask microsoft to support this.

Comment: The redirect uri is explicitly removed, and the state variable is the one you are supposed to put this all into, according to http://www.thread-safe.com/2014/05/the-correct-use-of-state-parameter-in.html

Comment: It appears that the [Azure Active Directory Developer support team's blog](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/11/state-parameter-in-mvc-application/) has referenced this answer so that is fairly official. Also [this Microsoft book](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2473126&seqNum=2) hints at this approach.