# Passing parameters to Azure Active Directory authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth, owin, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.Net MVC Application, Owin, and I'm using Azure Active Directory authentication as well.

I want to pass a parameter when the user is redirected to the Azure AD authentication page. So when the user signs in or signs up I want to pass `ProjectId (int)` as a parameter.

After the user signs in/up and is redirected to my Application I want to receive the `ProjectId` I passed as a parameter.

How can I achieve that?

edit: Adding code

```
// The ACR claim is used to indicate which policy was executed
public const string AcrClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnclassreference";
public const string PolicyKey = "b2cpolicy";
private const string OidcMetadataSuffix = "/.well-known/openid-configuration";

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
        ClientId = ClientId,
        RedirectUri = RedirectUri,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = RedirectUri,
        UseTokenLifetime = false,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
            SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated
        },
        Scope = "openid",
        ResponseType = "id_token",

        // The PolicyConfigurationManager takes care of getting the correct Azure AD authentication
        // endpoints from the OpenID Connect metadata endpoint.  It is included in the PolicyAuthHelpers folder.
        ConfigurationManager = new PolicyConfigurationManager(
            string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, AadInstance, Tenant, "/v2.0", OidcMetadataSuffix),
            new[] { SignUpPolicyId, SignInPolicyId, ProfilePolicyId }),

        // This piece is optional - it is used for displaying the user's name in the navigation bar.
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name"
        }
    };

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
}

private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(
        RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
    if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
    {
        var currentPolicy =
            notification.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseRevoke.AuthenticationTypes
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("b2c"));
        notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.Split('?')[0];
        notification.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("p", currentPolicy);
    }
    else
    {
        **// The value right now for the state is sort of "hijacked" and assigned by Microsoft**
        //notification.ProtocolMessage.Parameters["state"] = "OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=sRt-teBcxsd239viWo...... ";

        var currentPolicy = notification.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseChallenge.Properties
            .Dictionary[PolicyKey];
        notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.Split('?')[0];
        notification.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("p", currentPolicy);
    }

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}

private async Task OnSecurityTokenValidated(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
    await MyClass.CreatePrincipal(notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity);
}

private Task AuthenticationFailed(
            AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
    notification.HandleResponse();
    notification.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Similar to what Gaurav is suggesting, but adding a few special considerations. Basically, the state is used by the Owin middleware, so while you can inject your own stuff, you need to make sure you revert it back before the Owin middleware tries to use it otherwise you'll get auth errors.

This is effectively what I replied to a very similar question:

[Custom parameter with Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect and AzureAD v 2.0 endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489964/custom-parameter-with-microsoft-owin-security-openidconnect-and-azuread-v-2-0-en/37520329#37520329)

In Startup.Auth.cs, when you setup the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions you'd add the following:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
  new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
  {
    //...
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
      RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
      MessageReceived = OnMessageReceived
    },
  });
```

And use RedirectToIdentityProvider to inject your parameter, something along the lines of:

```
private static Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
  var stateQueryString = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=');
  var protectedState = stateQueryString[1];
  var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
  state.Dictionary.Add("mycustomparameter", "myvalue");
  notification.ProtocolMessage.State = stateQueryString[0] + "=" + notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(state);
  return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

And then use MessageReceived to extract it, like so:

```
private static Task OnMessageReceived(MessageReceivedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
  string mycustomparameter;
  var protectedState = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=')[1];
  var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
  state.Dictionary.TryGetValue("mycustomparameter", out mycustomparameter);
  return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

You'd obviously need to improve/harden this but this should get you going.

Comment: This answer dragged me out of a deep hole. Thank you so much! ‍♂️

Answer (score 4):

Just add `context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter(<ParameterName>, <value>);` in RedirectToIdentityProvider

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                    {
                        context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("prompt", "login");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the `ProjectId` parameter as value for `State` parameter. See the sample code below:

```
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                    {
                        redirectUri = string.Format("{0}/", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
                        postLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri + "sign-out";
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = redirectUri;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.State = "Your Project Id";
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var projectId = context.ProtocolMessage.State;//Retrieve the state in AuthorizationCodeReceived event.
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
            }
        };
```

**UPDATE**

Essentially `State` accepts a string parameter. In our project we needed to provide many values in the state. What we did there is created a pipe delimited string and pass that as state. When we receive the state back, we simply convert that into an array and use appropriate elements. Something like:

```
var state = "param1|param2|...|paramx";
```

Other thing you could do is create a state object (a simple class with some properties), serialize it as JSON, convert that in base64 string and pass that encoded string as state after properly url encoding it. When you receive back the state, you could do the reverse process, get state object back and use it's properties values.

Comment: Gaurav, thank you very much for helping. I wasn't able to set the context.ProtocolMessage.State because I already have a value assigned to it, the "OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=sRt- TokenValue". I even tried setting both values but I wasn't able to authenticate when I changed the OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties. Any ideas on how can I pass and receive a parameter?

Comment: Can you update your question and include code? That will certainly help.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer. See if this approach makes sense.

Comment: I tried something similar but if I change anything on the state the authentication doesn't work. I also tried your suggestion but it didn't work :(

Comment: If you have any other ideas let me know. Thank you very much for your assistance!!