# Redirection from Azure Active Directory authentication doesn't handle anchor in the URL in ASP.NET project with OpenID Connect?

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have a web site with Azure Active Directory authentication configured.

When visiting the web site like this, redirection from AAD authentication works well.
http://example.com/?a=b

When visiting the web site like this, the anchor (#) part of the URL will be dropped after redirection from AAD authentication.
http://example.com/#/search?a=b

The URL after redirection will become http://example.com.

How to make redirection work when there is anchor part in the URL? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the Azure AD middleware, but rather that the browser doesn't send the anchor to the server at all. The server handles redirecting to the login page and ensuring that the user gets redirected back to the web site afterwards, but since the server doesn't know about the anchor, the anchor gets lost in the redirection.

If you need to maintain the anchor after a login, then you will need to make some additional changes. For example, you could:

- Use adal.js and a popup window to do authentication so that the user never leaves the page.
- Use some custom mechanism, like a session cookie + some JavaScript so that the browser can remember which anchor value it had before being redirected and then re-apply it after the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

At present, the Azure AD doesn't support to pass the query string.

As a workaround, you may use the **state** parameter. More about the parameters support by the Azure AD, you can refer the links below:

[Authorize access to web applications using OAuth 2.0 and Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/)

[Authorize access to web applications using OpenID Connect and Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code/)

### Update

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "",
    ClientId = "",
    ClientSecret= "",
    Scope = "",
    RedirectUri = "",
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false
    },
    Notifications=new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications 
    {
        RedirectToIdentityProvider= onRedirectToIdentityProvider,
        MessageReceived= onMessageReceived
    }
});

private Task onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
    string mycustomparameter;
    var protectedState = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=')[1];
    var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
    state.Dictionary.TryGetValue("mycustomparameter", out mycustomparameter);
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}

private Task onRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
    var stateQueryString = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=');
    var protectedState = stateQueryString[1];
    var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
    state.Dictionary.Add("mycustomparameter", "myvalue");
    notification.ProtocolMessage.State = stateQueryString[0] + "=" + notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(state);
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: But I do see query string is retained after redirection when using http://example.com/?a=b. So is it just a coincidence?

Comment: I'm using OpenID Connect in an ASP.NET project. It looks like state has been leveraged in some way (by OpenID Connect middleware I guess). The value of state could look like "OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=...". Can I simply overwrite it to store the query string?

Comment: To add the custom query string using the OpenId OWIN component, we can custom the **Notifications** like this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770989/passing-parameters-to-azure-active-directory-authentication) discussed. I also update the code in the post.