# azuread oauth redirect_uri query parameter

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to add custom query parameters to the redirect_uri of an AzureAD OAuth flow?

We have tried but when the OAuth flow redirects back to the redirect_uri any query parameters we have added have been stripped off. I'm wondering if there is a way to configure the AzureAD application to keep such custom query parameters

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add custom query parameters to the redirect_uri of an AzureAD OAuth flow?

Yes, it is easy to add the custom query parameters if you were integrate Azure AD with OWIN. This question is also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770989/passing-parameters-to-azure-active-directory-authentication) and this is a code sample for your reference:

In Startup.Auth.cs, setup the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions like below:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
  new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
  {
    //...
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
      RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
      MessageReceived = OnMessageReceived
    },
  });
```

Inject the custom parameters use RedirectToIdentityProvider:

```
private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
  var stateQueryString = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=');
  var protectedState = stateQueryString[1];
  var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
  state.Dictionary.Add("mycustomparameter", "myvalue");
  notification.ProtocolMessage.State = stateQueryString[0] + "=" + notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(state);
  return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Then use MessageReceived to extract it:

```
private Task OnMessageReceived(MessageReceivedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
  string mycustomparameter;
  var protectedState = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=')[1];
  var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
  state.Dictionary.TryGetValue("mycustomparameter", out mycustomparameter);
  return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can see that I was a little unclear. 

We have one parameter that would prefer to have returned on the redirect_uri, not as part of the state, so we can decide which branch of logic to execute before examining the id_token and the state, but any dynamic query parameter that we add directly to the redirect_uri is stripped off when the authenticated request is redirected to request_uri.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: At present, the Azure AD doesn't support transfer the customer URL parameter from request to web app. The `OnMessageReceived` will be fired once your server get the message from identity data provider which is before OWIN validate the token.  Is it helpful?