# Using the State Parameter for Redirect URIs that Are Not Listed Explicitly in Azure AD Application Registration

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

My application which is hosted as an Azure App Service likes to email links to users telling them that it is their turn in the work flow. They click on it and should be able to log on and do the work that they need to do. However, I am getting the error `AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application:...`. In most cases, the link has either specific information in the URL route or as URL parameters and I can't possibly list all of the possibilities that could come up as a Redirect URI in the Azure AD application registration Authentication blade. Everything that I've read says to use a state param, but I really have no idea how to do that and can't find any real solid example.

I email a URL in this form to my user: `https://myapp.mycompany.com/edit?user=42&created=somedatetime`. When you click on it, it checks authentication here:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTennantId/oauth2/authorize
?response_type=id_token
&client_id=myClientId
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.mycompany.com%2Fedit?user=42&created=somedatetime
&state=33e9c826-5311-45b2-be01-5172862be124
&client-request-id=ba51438f-cd22-4fc4-8ea0-44fd69f3153b
&x-client-SKU=Js
&x-client-Ver=1.0.17
&nonce=08f67a4e-1bf9-4c43-9771-e0b61684b465
```

Now there is a state parameter in that URL, but I have no idea where it's coming from or how it's generated (obviously it's a GUID, but I mean I don't see how it's mapping to any kind of state). Furthermore, I would have to drop the encoded parameters from my redirect URI parameter, and then where does it go? I am just simply stumped at how I would set my application up to use that state param.

What's funny, is that I'm really just seeing this now that I created a new App Service application for this existing app which is using the same Azure AD application registration that I was using before. I feel like I am completely misunderstanding this.

Any one (really) know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you got to check if the redirect uri added in app registration redirect uri in azure ad is same as that configured in the application ?Have you included your apps url in redirect uri according to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-create-an-app-registration-in-azure-ad-for-your-app-service-app) .Also check  [reference](http://jsandersblog.azurewebsites.net/2018/01/30/azure-app-service-error-aadsts50011-the-reply-address-http-azurewebsites-netsignin-oidc-does-not-match-the-reply-addresses-configured-for-the-application/)

Comment: "In most cases, the link has either specific information in the URL route or as URL parameters and I can't possibly list all of the possibilities that could come up as a Redirect URI in the Azure AD application" So, no, I can't possibly list the specific URL, but just the base URL.

Comment: We have decided to go with using query parameters for any specific criteria while still using certain routes for more generic parts of the app (e.g. `http:/myapp.org/editing?user=someuserid&created=somedatetime`). That way I can put the URL left of the question mark into the app registration in Azure AD. I don't feel this answers my question, but I think this works much better. I guess I had too much of a RESTful mindset, but this isn't an API, it's a SPA.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below given references can narrow down your issue.

1. I would request you to check the "Authentication blade" in the App Registration for the required app "App id" and see if reply url given in code configuration is same as that registered in azure ad .Make sure both are same .

(or)

2. If a state parameter is included in the request, the same value should appear in the response.(Then it is successful response from a secure user). This helps to detect Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks .So this way azure helps to secure application.

> The state parameter is a string so you can encode any other
> information in it. You send a random value when starting an
> authentication request and validate the received value when processing
> the response. You store something on the client application side (in
> cookies, session, or localstorage) that allows you to perform the
> validation.
>
> If you receive a response with a state that doesn't match, you can
> infer that you may be the target of an attack because this is either a
> response for an unsolicited request or someone trying to forge the
> response.

You may need to pass a random string value in state parameter or any project related id or anything when constructing the authorization request.[Reference](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.1)

You may use **RedirectToIdentityProvider** to inject your parameter and try with Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Please Check the references below that may help.

1. [asp.net mvc - Passing parameters to Azure Active Directory authentication - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770989/passing-parameters-to-azure-active-directory-authentication) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489964/custom-parameter-with-microsoft-owin-security-openidconnect-and-azuread-v-2-0-en/37520329#37520329)
2. [How to use 'state' parameter to inject custom parameter](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/11/state-parameter-in-mvc-application/)
3. [Pass custom state in authentication requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-pass-custom-state-authentication-request)
4. [Passing state  - Honza’s Blarg](https://hajekj.net/2018/06/12/passing-state-through-authentication-in-asp-net-core/)

Some browsers will get this error because of the limitation of the URL length. Try to set storeAuthStateInCookie to "true" to save the cache .
For example:

```
cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true, 
    },
```

Else you may raise a support request regarding the same.