# How to use end client state parameter in IdentityServer 3?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, identityserver3

I have configured IdentityServer 3 to use external `IdentityProvider` which is pointing to AAD.

As of now, when I send a request to `IdentityServer`, I am properly redirected to the AAD for login, however, the 'state' parameter that I am sending to IdentityServer is overridden, and the value of `OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties` is encrypted and sent to the AAD as the state in the query string.

For eg:

```
https://localhost:44333/idpaad/connect/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44394/&response_mode=query&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email&state=9b0e82c3-e623-42f1-bede-493243c103e7
```

Here,
`https://localhost:44333/idpaad/connect/authorize` -> `IdentityServer` endpoint
`state=9b0e82c3-e623-42f1-bede-493243c103e7` -> client generated GUID sent as querystring.

when I see in the "`RedirectToIdentityProvider`" middleware in the StartUp.cs of IdentityServer OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications, the value of state is updated to
`OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=(protected values)` instead of the GUID and the same is also returned as a query string back to the Redirect URI.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LukZp.png)
Is there a way to send the original state and not override it by IdentityServer3?

While using wsFederation, I am not getting this issue and the same is forwarded directly to the IdP.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:
* Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core - https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time it's advisable for an Azure Active Directory integrated application to maintain an application state when sending request to Azure AD for login. **And the recommended way to achieve this is to use the ‘state’ parameter as defined in the OpenID Connect standards**.

If you check this [document](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#rfc.section.3.1.2.1) form OpenID, you will find that **primary reason for using the `state` parameter is to mitigate CSRF attacks**.

> RECOMMENDED. Opaque value used to maintain state between the request and the callback. Typically, Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF, XSRF) mitigation is done by cryptographically binding the value of this parameter with a browser cookie.

The ‘state’ parameter is used for both **preventing cross-site request forgery attacks and to maintain user’s state before authentication request occurs**.

In an `ASP.NET or ASP.NET CORE` web application using **OpenID Connect OWIN middleware**, the **`‘state’ parameter` is maintained automatically by the middleware when sending out an authentication request**, this is the only reason you are seeing the state parameter getting overridden in your case.

But if you want you can add custom data in your state parameter. Use the following code in **OpenIdConnectNotifications’s RedirectToIdentityProvider** event to inject custom data into the ‘state’ parameter.

```js
var stateQueryString = notification.ProtocolMessage.State.Split('=');
var protectedState = stateQueryString[1];
var state = notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(protectedState);
state.Dictionary.Add("MyData","123");
notification.ProtocolMessage.State = stateQueryString[0] + "=" + notification.Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(state);
```

Check this [document](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/11/state-parameter-in-mvc-application/) and [Microsoft identity platform and OpenID Connect protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc) for detailed information.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have a client which is calling the identity server through this endpoint, however, when I come to the RedirectToIdentityProvider event, the data which was sent is not maintained and is lost. I wanted to do exactly as you suggested, but how to carry the 'state' information to that event? Unfortunately, that is now a roadblock for me and any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489964/custom-parameter-with-microsoft-owin-security-openidconnect-and-azuread-v-2-0-en/37520329#37520329) by @Saca. You can also raise a ticket at Microsoft Support for more help.

Comment: Yes, I did look at the answer, unfortunately, it is not solving my purpose. This talks about how to use the values when it comes back from the AAD into the middleware. I want a mechanism to fetch the client query string information into the middleware.. I have posted a ticket at Microsoft Support. Thanks for all the help!!