# Unable to retain user state when performing SSO using Azure B2c as redirect URI is pointing to homepage

Tags: azure, url, parameters, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I have implemented Azure SSO using open ID connect, I am redirecting a user to the homepage of my portal once he is logged in using an office account.

The problem is since the redirect URL(localhost:443/abc/test.aspx) is a constant that we have to put, I could not figure out how to retain a URL where a user was before login (e.g. localhost:443/abc/test.aspx#/item/30176). After SSO login it redirect me to only localhost:443/abc/test.aspx, I want to land to localhost:443/abc/test.aspx#/item/30176 (30176 is variable item id)

If state is the only way to go. I could not find how to use it. Any references of implementation would really be helpful

Comment: What programming language are you using? Are you using MSAL?

Comment: c# .NET . I can use MSAL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489964/custom-parameter-with-microsoft-owin-security-openidconnect-and-azuread-v-2-0-en/37520329#37520329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   You can surely use the ‘state’ parameter for this purpose to redirect the user after successful authentication to the same page before login, but it needs to be configured in the authentication request that is sent in ‘MSAL.js’ script. The state parameter can also be used to encode information of the app's state before redirect. You can pass the user's state in the app, such as the page or view they were on, as input to this parameter. The MSAL.js library allows you to pass your custom state as state parameter in the Request object as below: -

```
    // Request type
          export type AuthenticationParameters = {
           scopes?: Array<string>;
 extraScopesToConsent?: Array<string>;
  prompt?: string;
    extraQueryParameters?: QPDict;
   claimsRequest?: string;
    authority?: string;
    state?: string;
    correlationId?: string;
    account?: Account;
    sid?: string;
    loginHint?: string;
     forceRefresh?: boolean;
     };
```

You can refer the below documentation links for more details on including this parameter in the Azure AD B2C redirect links: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-pass-custom-state-authentication-request

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow

Answer (score 0):

consider using a cookie to remember the original URL. Redirect it after the user authenticates.

Comment: I would probably not want to add any code to client side as multiple portal would need SSO eventually. Not sure if client agrees to add some logic on his side.  Is there some functionality provided by Azure Active Directory. Would it be possible thru state parameter but I am not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In java I'm calling this URL

```
https://YOUR_TENANT_NAME.b2clogin.com/YOUR_TENANT_NAME.onmicrosoft.com/YOUR_POLICY_NAME/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&nonce=RANDOM_UNIQUE_STRING&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&scope=openid&response_type=code&state=URLEncoder.encode(params.referer, "UTF-8")
```

//params.referer is my URL which is used by my backend to redirect the customer where s/he was before logging in/authorization.

And after successful authorization, I'm getting the state (MY_REDIRECT_URL) value along with the authorization code.

[Here is a Github sample java code for Azure AD B2C SSO](https://github.com/mahfuzcmt/Azure-AD-B2C-SSO)